# how to create custom widget in mapguide fusion template?

Tags: web-mapping, mapguide, mapguide-maestro

I am using mapguide maestro 5.0.1. I want to add custom fusion widget which have option to search layer in multiple ways. I am not able to find any tutorial to add custom widget useful. can you please suggest any tutorial which explain  everything in detail. I have working module of this option in ajaxviewer can I use it in fusion.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the short answer here, but it should get you started at least:

- Check out the current widgets in fusion/widgets directory. Go through some or most of them and you'll get the hang of the pattern
- Add the widget in via maestro or in your fusion layout js file. Again, look at the current default layout file for samples (or even the Autodesk basic demo ones). Basically, you load the widget class, then create interface buttons use JXLib and place it on the interface.

Good luck!